# Maximizing a non-concave objective

Tags: optimization

I want to maximize this function
$\log_2(1+p)+e^{-p} $.

The second derivative is 
$-\frac{1}{\ln2 (1+p)^2}+e^{-p}$

Is there any way to get a unique solution for p ?

Comment: Find critical point(s) $p_i$ and check with the $2$nd derivative.

Comment: maximizing on where?   on "R" function is unbouded

Comment: @farruhota The second derivative>0 which means it is not concave

Comment: @Red shoes $p=[0, p_{max}]$, p is bounded by a maximum value $p_{max}$

Answer (score 0):

There is no extreme (max/min) point.

Note that the function has the domain:
$$1+p>0\Rightarrow p>-1.$$
Also note that the function is increasing in its domain:
$$f'(p)=\frac{1}{(p+1)\ln{2}}-\frac{1}{e^p}>0, \ \ \ for \ \ \ p>-1.$$

Also note:
$$\lim_\limits{p\to-1^{+}}\left[\frac{1}{\ln 2}\cdot\ln(1+p)+\frac{1}{e^p}\right]=-\infty$$
$$\lim_\limits{p\to+\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\ln 2}\cdot\ln(1+p)+\frac{1}{e^p}\right]=+\infty$$